# Meromorphic function at conjugate

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a meromorphic function. Is it true that $f(\bar{z})=\overline{f(z)}$ for all complex numbers $z$?

A meromorphic function can be written as a ratio of two holomorphic functions. Moreover, at any point $s\in\mathbb{C}$, the function $f$ can be expressed as a Laurent series in a neighborhood of $s$. But still, the Laurent series is different at $s$ than at $\bar{s}$. How can we show the result?

Comment: It's certainly true if $s$, the center of the series, is real, and the coefficients are real as well.

Comment: It's true if $f(z)$ is real when $z$ is real (Schwarz reflection principle)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function $f(z) = i$ is meromorphic, but does not satisfy your property.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Schwarz reflection principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_reflection_principle), this is true if $f$ takes real values along the real axis. It is not true in general.